# Jquery rotate image when click and reset again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is what I want in simple

I want to rotate(180) a image(arow.png) when someone clicks it. And then again i want it to reset when the user click on it for the second time.

For now I am using a simple JS with css but with css I cannot reset it. Can anyone help.I am a newbie for coding.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".footer-button").click(function(){
jQuery(".footer-popup").slideToggle("slow");

 jQuery(".footer-button").css({
   "transform":"rotate(180deg)",
   "-webkit-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
   "-moz-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
   "-ms-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
   "-o-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
   "transition":"transform 0.5s ease-in-out"});

  });
});
```

Comment: A jsfiddle for this, would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now what you are doing is adding CSS to `(".footer-button")` when it is clicked. The same CSS would be added to the button the second, third, etc time you click it. Therefore the button would not be reset no matter how many times you click on it.

You may be thinking that giving an element `"transform":"rotate(180deg)"` again would rotate it 180 degree again. And that is a huge misconception of how [CSS3 transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) works.

What `"transform":"rotate(180deg)"` really does is to make the element in a state rotated 180 degree relative to its original rotation (0deg). To get the element back to the original state, you either remove `"transform":"rotate(180deg)"` or change the CSS back to `"transform":"rotate(0deg)"`.

In JavaScript you would need to implement it yourself so that it would change the CSS again on the second click. It can be easily done using a boolean variable and an if-statement like this:

```
var clicked = false;

$(".footer-button").click(function(){
  var deg = clicked ? 0 : 180;  
  //when it is not clicked, rotates 180 deg, else rotates 0 deg.
  this.css({
    "transform":"rotate("+deg+"deg)",
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate("+deg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate("+deg+"deg)",
    "-ms-transform": "rotate("+deg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotate("+deg+"deg)"
  });
  clicked = !clicked;
})
```

If you want the second rotation to be in clockwise motion, you would need to set it to 360 instead of 0.

Oh, and you don't have to set `"transition":"transform 0.5s ease-in-out"` in the JS. You can just have that in your CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on this simple HTML5 code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;

    }   
.rotate:hover   
{ 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="arrow.png" class="rotate" />
</body>
</html>
```

Add your image instead of `arrow.png`. You can change the degree from 360 to 180.

Hope it will helps you.. 
Thank you !